# Replace string in ruby

Tags: ruby

My path in the logs is coming as:

```
/ref/bts/prj/references/animatic/myimage_284.tif?1421934337
```

Sometimes its `tif`, `tga`, `cin`, etc.

How can I replace my string after `.` and before `?` with jpg format so that it is always displayed on the browser as in my folder I always have `jpg` image format.

Comment: who requests that image?

Comment: If I upload the image with .tif, .cin, .err, etc.. extensions then that is not dispalyed on my browser. So in my folder I also created the imaged with jpg extension using image magick convert method. So I have to replace the extension with jpg in my path

Comment: Done it using path.split("?")[0][/[^.]+/]+ ".jpg" +"?"+ path.split("?")[1]

Comment: What I was asking is: what is trying to load that one image with these different extensions? You should change _that_ so that it requests the correct .jpg image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gsub` and replace the extension with a regular expression.

If your string is saved in a variable called `path`, you can do:

```
path.gsub(/\.([a-z]+)\?/, '.jpg?')
```

which will replace the extension with "jpg", regardless of what it is.

In other words

```
"/ref/bts/prj/references/animatic/myimage_284.tif?1421934337".gsub(/\.([a-z]+)\?/, '.jpg?')
= "/ref/bts/prj/references/animatic/myimage_284.jpg?1421934337"
```

If you want to fine tune your regular expression, [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/) is a nice place to play around and get to know ruby regex